# Transfering/Segregating certain elements of an array to other arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Let's say the user inputted the numbers 10, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, & 99 into an array. Then the program has to segregate the numbers below 50 and above 50 into two different arrays namely array2 and array3. But when I run my program it would display some garbage memory in array2 and array3.

My program would run with the display:

**Numbers in array1**

```
10, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99
```

**Numbers in array2**

```
1972394090, 22, 33, 44, 0, 4202032, 2686624, 2686680, 2686924, 10, 11
```

**Numbers in array3**

```
2686700, 4202032, 0, 2686604, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 1972394134, 1972394090
```

this is my function code(N is defined as 10)

```
void segArr(int array[N], int array2[N], int array3[N])
{

    int i;


    for(i=1; i<N; i++)
    {
        if(array[i]<50)
            array2[i]=array[i];
        if(array[i]>50)
            array3[i]=array[i];
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: what did you expect the element, say, `array2[1]` to contain? You didn't assign anything to it, so it will contain random bits. **I recomment learning C++ before asking**

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to do something like this:

```
const int split=50;
int n2=0, n3=0;
for(int i1=0; i1!=n1; ++i1)
  if(array1[i1] < split)
    array2[n2++] = array1[i1];
  else
    array3[n3++] = array1[i1];
// n2,n3 now hold the filled sizes of array2 and array3
```

Of course, all this is much better done using `std` containers ... In particular, you may be interested in [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) or [`std::stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition), which rearrange the order or elements in an array/container.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, array indices start at 0 not 1.  Secondly, you're indeed copying the array elements of interest, but whatever old array content was in `array2` and `array3` is not cleared first, and obviously wasn't set in the calling code either: that's why when you print the array elements out you see "garbage" values like `1972394090`, though technically it's undefined behaviour to even try to print an uninitialised value and you could equally have the program abort or otherwise malfunction.

You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
void segArr(int array[N], int array2[N], int array3[N])
{
    size_t i2 = 0, i3 = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (array[i] < 50)
            array2[i2++] = array[i];
        else if (array[i] > 50)
            array3[i3++] = array[i];
    }
    if (i2 < N) array2[i2] = 50;
    if (i3 < N) array3[i3] = 50;
}
```

That way you can print out the `array2` and `array3` elements 0 through N-1, stopping early if you see a `50` value.  (I use 50 as an end-of-results *sentinel* value because it's the only integer value that you could never have in `array2` nor `array3`.)

Comment: @Walter: Yes, quite deliberately... only the elements at the start of each - up until either the sentinel value 50 or element `[N-1]` if there is no 50 - will not be garbage.  I see no point wasting time/code setting those elements to anything other than garbage when the sentinel makes it clear where the meaningful data stops.  When you loop printing them out, stop when you see 50 and all the earlier-printed values should not be garbage.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I obviously havn't read your answer fully (but only the code)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you probably declare vector like this:

```
std::vector<int> array2(10);
```

and display every element in that vector. If some element is empty you display random data.

you should just iniciaze vector, and than use push_back()
f.e.

```
if(array[i]>50)
array2.push_back(array[i]);
```